# Как дождаться загрузки данных после функции load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Как дождаться загрузки данных после функции load?
небольшой примерчик:

```js
$("#hideitem").load(link);
alert($("#hideitem").html()); // здесь пока пусто, нужно подождать. как это сделать?
```

Comment: прочитать документацию?) http://api.jquery.com/load/ (callback fuction)

Comment: Вам дать ссылку на канонический ответ по асинхронщине или это будет издевательством? :)

Comment: @ThisMan ссылка это как бы не ответ, особенно на энглише и для рунета

Comment: @perfect, я оформил как ответ? Я оставил комментарий, да и к тому же без английского в программирование лучше не соваться

Comment: @perfect тогда вот на русском http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_HTML-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85  :D

Comment: @ThisMan да я то уже почитал. но мне хотелось бы что бы гугол меня по моему запросу привел именно сюда

Comment: @perfect тогда напишите ответ сами

Comment: @PavelMayorov окей

Comment: @Grundy - это **совсем** не дубликат! Тут загвоздка не в, собственно, получении значения при имеющемся API - а в чтении документации :)

Comment: @Grundy я конечно понимаю что jquery написан js но это не одно и то же

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Раз вы нашли метод [load](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ajax_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81_HTML-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85), то вы могли увидеть, что он выглядит так:

```
.load(url,[data],[callback],[dataType]):
```

и что у него третьим параметром можно написать `callback` функцию, которая будет вызвана после того, как присланный сервером html-текст будет помещен в выбранные элементы страницы. Собссн его и надо написать и использовать.

Пример:

```
$("#result").load(
  "ajax/test.php",
  {
    param1: "param1",
    param2: 2
  },
  function(){alert("Получен ответ от сервера.")}
);
```

Comment: спасибо. достойный ответ вместо холивара

Comment: @perfect на самом деле он намекает, что нужно немного повнимательней изучать некоторые функции, которые используете. Возможно иногда (часто) вы не всё знаете и нужно это проверить

Comment: дело в другом. почему когда я гуглю на английском то по любому пуку попадаю на английский SO где есть ответ с кучей плюсов... они тупые? как вы считаете? ... или невнимательные?

Comment: @perfect если не вбивать в поле поиска дополнительно слово  Stackoverflow то нормально всё гуглиться :D  ......... вот я вбил `jquery load` http://s018.radikal.ru/i518/1702/78/1a071a061d9c.jpg      первые ссылки  ведут в доки по JQuery на на английском, на русском и в W3S  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: а вы вот так гуглить пробовали `jquery load wait` и посмотрим куда вы попадете...

Comment: @perfect там вполне выпадают ссылки на доки. Но, как бы то ни было, уж что-что, а на Jquery очень много доков в т.ч. на русском, в которых все популярные используемые методы подробно описаны и даже с примерами. Поэтому банально стоит в начале хотя бы открыть используемый метод, ознакомиться и если ничего подходящего нет - гуглить уже по форумам и so, кмк

Comment: гугл придуман для "очеловеченого" поиска. я уверен что по моему запросу вы увидели ваш же ответ только на английском языке. я не прав?