# В userscript не срабатывает функция jQuery load()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь создать свой первый userscript (Chrome + Violentmonkey).

Есть сайт со списком ссылок на другие страницы **этого же сайта**.
На сайт можно зайти **только с авторизацией**(может быть это важно).

Пытаюсь в подсказки к ссылкам добавить текст со страниц куда они ссылаются. Но процесс застревает на функции load() (jquery-3.3.1), а точнее - ощущение что эта функция игнорируется - до и после неё код выполняется, она сама нет, и не выдаёт никаких сообщений, консоль ошибок пустая. Пробовал просто другую jQuery функцию - работает.

Где ошибка или ограничение? Как можно сделать по другому?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name RTHelper
// @include https://site.ru/
// ==/UserScript==
// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
(function (window, undefined) {
    var w;
    if (typeof unsafeWindow != undefined) {
        w = unsafeWindow
    } else {
        w = window;
    }
    if (w.self != w.top) {
        return;
    }
    if (/https:\/\/site.ru/.test(w.location.href)) {
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            // Взять список элементов
            var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName('list-item');
            // Текущий url адрес
            var url = window.location.toString();
            // Тестировать только на первом элементе
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                var aElements = listItems[i].getElementsByTagName('a');
                var aElement = aElements[0];
                var itemUrl = url + aElement.getAttribute('href');
                // такая конструкция для отлова багов в функции загрузки
                var hMessages = $(".messagebody").load(itemUrl, function(response, status, xhr) {
                    if (status == "error") {
                      var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
                      alert(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
                    }
                    else { alert("ELSE!")
                    }
                });

                // Выдаёт 0
                alert(hMessages.length);

                // Тут начинаю подстановку подсказок
            };
        });
    };
}) (window);
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623916/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-load

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не похоже. У него алерты в коллбэке.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, Спасибо, ваш комментарий навёл меня на нужную дорогу.

Answer (score 0):

Неправильное использование метода load (http://api.jquery.com/load/)
Оказывается он добавляет в конкретный элемент текущей страницы, элемент с загружаемой страницы.
Так в div c ID newdiv загружаем элемент с ID footer с адреса itemUrl.

```
$("#newdiv").load(itemUrl + ' #footer')
```

Я ожидал, что могу загрузить в переменную список загруженных элементов и работать с ними.